# Unit testing code targeting several frameworks at once with .NET Core and xUnit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit.net

I have some libraries on .NET Core which target `net45` and `netstandard1.6` and I want to unit-test them. I did `dotnet new -t xunittest` and that created a new test project targeting `netcoreapp1.0` so that it will tests only the .NET Core code.

I tried to also compile it to target also `net45` but then I got a series of errors on test discovering. My questions is

Is there a way to test the code targeting both (maybe more later) frameworks with a single test project or should I make a test project for each one I target?

**Edit**: here are my `project.json` and the messages I'm getting:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
        "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

these are the errors I get once the project is compiled:

```
dotnet-test Error: 0 : [ReportingChannel]: Waiting for message failed System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data om the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> stem.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.ReportingChannel.ReadMessages()
>dotnet-test Error: 0 : Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport nnection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> stem.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.ReportingChannel.ReadMessages()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object ate)
[ReportingChannel]: Error sending System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Cannot cess a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, cketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.ReportingChannel.Send(Message message)
dotnet-test Error: 0 : System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Cannot access a sposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, cketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.ReportingChannel.Send(Message message)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.ReportingChannel.SendError(String error)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.ReportingChannel.SendError(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.DesignTimeRunner.HandleDesignTimeMessages(ProjectContext projectContext, tnetTestParams dotnetTestParams)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.DesignTimeRunner.DoRunTests(ProjectContext projectContext, DotnetTestParams tnetTestParams)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.BaseDotnetTestRunner.RunTests(ProjectContext projectContext, DotnetTestParams tnetTestParams, BuildWorkspace workspace)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.TestCommand.DoRun(String[] args)
```

and finalizes with this line

```
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:03.0417342) ==========
```

although I know I have one test (so far at least).

however If I remove the `net 45` references all works like charm, here is my working `project.json`:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "buildOptions": {
      "debugType": "portable"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
      "xunit": "2.1.0",
      "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
   },
   "testRunner": "xunit",
   "frameworks": {
      "netcoreapp1.0": {
         "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
               "type": "platform",
               "version": "1.0.0"
             }
         },
         "imports": [
         "dotnet5.4",
         "portable-net451+win8"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors that you got? And could you describe in more details what you did, so that we can reproduce the errors?

Comment: @svick I have just edited my question adding the errors and `project.json` data. Hope that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [xUnit .NET Core docs](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html#targeting-desktop),

> You can target both `net4xx` and `netcoreapp` simply by adding both frameworks together in your `project.json` file. When you run `dotnet test` with multiple framework entries, the system will run all your framework tests, one after another.

This doesn't mean that you can have a single test project reference and test project that target *different* platforms (like a .NET 4.5 project and a .NET Core project). But it does mean that you can test projects that target the same *set* of platforms.

For example, I have a class library that targets both .NET 4.5.1 and .NET Core:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {},
    "net451":  {} 
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

I can target `net451` and `netcoreapp1.0` in my test project, and reference this class library:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "NetStandardClassLibrary": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {},
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

When `dotnet test` is executed, tests will run twice (once for each platform target):

```
λ dotnet test
Project NetStandardClassLibrary (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project XunitBothFrameworks (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
xUnit.net .NET CLI test runner (64-bit .NET Core win81-x64)
  Discovering: XunitBothFrameworks
  Discovered:  XunitBothFrameworks
  Starting:    XunitBothFrameworks
  Finished:    XunitBothFrameworks
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   XunitBothFrameworks  Total: 1, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 0.244s
Project NetStandardClassLibrary (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project XunitBothFrameworks (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
xUnit.net .NET CLI test runner (64-bit Desktop .NET win81-x64)
  Discovering: XunitBothFrameworks
  Discovered:  XunitBothFrameworks
  Starting:    XunitBothFrameworks
  Finished:    XunitBothFrameworks
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   XunitBothFrameworks  Total: 1, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 0.201s
SUMMARY: Total: 2 targets, Passed: 2, Failed: 0.
```

When I tried to run the tests inside Visual Studio, I got a similar error message as you. I think it's a bug, because `dotnet test` on the command line worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the below `project.json` worked nicely, I didn't have to run the test from `cmd`.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Moq": "4.5.22",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "IntegraPay.Domain": { "version": "1.0.0-*","target": "project" },
    "Integrapay.RegistrationApplication": { "version": "", "target": "project" }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "net451"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```